# Getting data from Firestore to display a go template file

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, go-templates

How can I get the p.template from firestore, which is a string, into template.ParseFiles function? Is it possible to use the field value in the function to select the correct template file?

```
type Property struct {
    Name            string        `firestore:"name"`
    ApprovedOrigins []interface{} `firestore:"approvedOrigins"`
    Template        string        `firestore:"selected"`
}
```

As you can see above the firestore field name is `selected`

```
func serveHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, params map[string]string) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, projectId)
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: Handle error.
        log.Println("FIREBASE ERROR:", err)
    }

    // collection group query in firestore
    q := client.CollectionGroup("data").Where("approvedOrigins", "array-contains", r.Host).Limit(1)

    // iterate through the document query
    iter := q.Documents(ctx)
    defer iter.Stop()
    for {
        doc, err := iter.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            // TODO: Handle error.
            log.Println("FIREBASE ERROR:", err)
        }

        fmt.Println("Database connected...")

        var p Property
        if err := doc.DataTo(&p); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(p.Template) // This is not logging any data/string

        t, _ := template.ParseFiles(p.Template + ".html")   
        fmt.Println(t.Execute(w, p)) //504 error happens here

    }
}
```

Comment: `Property.template` is unexported. I do not know the firebase driver, but mapping unexported fields usually does not work.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I've updated the question with the struct.

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too. Specifically, your question lacks a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide an entry of Firestore with all the field.
Have all the documents you are iterating over all fields?